# Javascript window.open() on Internet Explorer 11 when open intranet website not work correctly

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, window.open

I'm trying to fix a issue that Internet Explorer ignore parameters of function window.open() when open intranet web site. It's work correctly when open site in internet zone. I Can't figure out why this function don't work in intranet zone. Options not working in intranet zone: "scrollbars=no,menubar=no,resizable=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no"

```js
window.open('page.aspx?width=' + width + '&height=' + height, '', 'width=' + width + ',height=' + height + ',scrollbars=no,menubar=no,resizable=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,fullscreen=no,top=' + top + ',left=' + left);
```

Comment: Please define "_not work correctly_". What do you expect the code to do, and what it does instead?

Comment: Just to be clear: what do you understand with "intranet zone"? (I am asking that because the browser does not care about those "zones" tbh)

Comment: This options not work in intranet zone: "scrollbars=no,menubar=no,resizable=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no".

Comment: With normal security settings those options wouldn't work in internet zone either. Add the page to the trusted sites in the intranet zone too.

Comment: Unfortunately adding the site to the intranet zone list has no effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Teemu has [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52622022/javascript-window-open-on-internet-explorer-11-when-open-intranet-website-not/52622797#comment92178037_52622022) it is normal that those options don't work. What it is weird is that they work in the Internet zone, they shouldn't out of the box. Check if there is any customization to the security settings.

A browser can ignore some parameters of `windows.open()` out of security reasons (like hiding information or spoofing interfaces). The fact that you get a different behavior in different security zones suggests that it is exactly your problem.

You need to tinker the security settings in the intranet zone.

Have a look to [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531202%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to understand window restrictions in IE and to this other for [browsing security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb457150(v=technet.10)#ECAA) under Windows. They are old but main principles still apply.